# correct number of observations

Tags: r, count, subset

I am running some statistics in R on a data set to see if there is any difference between the groups.  so I i have done the following

```
DATA$time <- difftime(data$endtime, data$starttime, unites ="mins")
```

I then want to subset so I only get positive time

```
DATA$time1 <- difftime(data$endtime, data$starttime, unites ="mins") [DATA$time>0 & DATAtime < 2000]
```

At this point i get a warning message.

```
In `[.data.table`(x,j =`(name, value=value):

Supplied 43242 items to be assigned to 45649 items of column 'time'
(recycled leaving remainder of 2407 items).
```

However i am still able to rund the next line of code...

```
DATA[,.(numbers=sum(length(!is.na(Agegroup))), min=min(time1, na.rm =
T), mean=mean(time1, na.rm = T),max=max(time1, na.rm =
T),SEM=sd(time1, na.rm = T)/sqrt(length(time1))), by= DATA$Agegroup]

#DATA  numbers   min       mean         max      SEM 
#1: 0  42897   1 mins    609.4079 mins 1439 mins 1.500116 
#2: 4  1525    5 mins    615.8830 mins 1430 mins 8.004109 
#3: 5  286     80 mins   592.0000 mins 1430 mins 19.020898 
#4: 3  796     5 mins    629.2510 mins 1430 mins 11.013346 
#5: 7  16      225 mins  596.9231 mins 1100 mins 62.248533 
#6: 1  26      250 mins  624.1667 mins 1315 mins 63.108800 
#7: 2  16      90 mins   567.8571 mins 1050 mins 88.852221 
#8: 6  87      50 mins   651.3519 mins 1430 mins 35.799050
```

I have two questions.

**1)** how do I get R to return numbers as numbers used for the calculation? 
 - when I add all numbers i get 45649 but I am assuming that I should get 43242? or how does this work? if not, what are the remaining 2407? and how do I get them out of my statistics if they do not meet the requirements for my subsetting?

**2)** is there a way to have R returning the results by order of Agegroup? right now the order is 0,4,5,3,7,1,2,6 I would like it to be 1-7

Thanks in advance for any possible help or guidance to help me.

Answer (score 0):

`DATA$time1 <- difftime(data$endtime, data$starttime, unites ="mins") [DATA$time>0 & DATAtime < 2000]` tries to assign a result that is too small to a larger `data.table`.  That's what the error message is saying. If you think about it, this makes sense since you are subsetting based on some criteria but putting it back to the same size of `data.table`

You can check the return value  of the `difftime` like this in your console:

```
X <-  difftime(data$endtime, data$starttime, unites ="mins") [DATA$time>0 & DATAtime < 2000]
length(X)
X
```

You should look into using the `dplyr` library. They are more beginner user friendly.

You could try the following to achieve what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%mutate(time = difftime(endtime, starttime, unit ="mins")) %>%
mutate(time1 = ifelse((time > 0 && time < 2000), difftime(endtime, starttime, unit ="mins"), NA)
```

You can use the `arrange` function to sort

Here is a link to a cheatsheet for `dplyr`
https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Basically what has happened is that when you created your second vector `(DATA$time1)` you generated a subset of your data that is shorter than the other vector `(DATA$time)` that is present, so R has recycled the first numbers from `DATA$time1` to fill in the remaining empty vector space, leaving 2407 unused from this recycling. This happens because you have atomic vectors.

You might find it easier to remove the variables you don't want than to keep rather than trying to select those you do want. It is difficult to say exactly how this would work without a minimal example dataset, but you might have to coerce your data to a matrix or use functions that coerce the data into a non-vector form.